# Git push is not working

Tags: git, github, push

I am trying to push the local repo on github but `git push` is not working for me following is error

```
git push https://github.com/MandarSant/Mandars_First_Repo.git master
To https://github.com/MandarSant/Mandars_First_Repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MandarSant/Mandars_First_Repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: As it mentions you have to reconcile the remote branch with your local one first, so `git pull` then `git push`

Comment: git pull origin master --rebase

Comment: Did you even read the error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like the error message says, the repo that you are trying to push to has been modified by someone else. In order for you to be able to push to a repository, you should have the latest changes.

So what you gotta do is make sure that you tell git, that you know about the changes that were made by the other person. The way to do it is to do a `git pull`. Once you do that, you should be able to push to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

What has happened is someone else has pushed to master and you don't have those changes locally

pull from master to merge their changes with yours and then you can push

Answer (score 0):

If I had a dime for everytime someone didn't read error messages...

You need to `git pull` before you `git push`

Comment: but accordint to video tut here he didnt do pull before [Git & GitHub Tutorial for Beginners #10 - Introduction to GitHub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQLK8Ib_SKk&t=397s)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute `git pull` command before pushing anything to git repository.
If may sometime inform you that some files would be overwritten by merge, in that case you have to stash your changes or copy those files in another place and then have to revert the changes, then after pull apply your changes.